# Register SQL Server 2019 in Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I am trying to register a SQL Server instance in Active Directory. I followed the instructions at https://help.zaptechnology.com/zap%20cubexpress/currentversion/content/topics/HowTo/UsingSPN.htm, but `Get-ADObject -Filter "objectclass -eq 'MS-SQL-SQLServer'"` returns no results.

Also I tried instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189776(v=sql.105) then found out active directory integration support is discontinued since SQL Server 2012.

How can I add SQL Server object to Active Directory?

If the support for integration from SQL Server side is dropped, is SQL Server table in Active Directory obsolete?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  When you install SQL Server on a Domain-joined server no other action is typically required.

Comment: I am trying to test a feature from my app that collects last backup date for databases. I have installed SQLServer in DC itself (I know it is not recommended), do I need to install in a domain joined computer instead?

Comment: What does that have to do with Active Directory?

Comment: Not sure! I installed in a domain joined computer and set up SPN for user, still Get-ADObject -Filter "objectclass -eq 'MS-SQL-SQLServer'" returns no result.

Comment: I don't even know if there's supposed to be anything there.  Why are you looking at AD in the first place?  It's probably not the right solution.

Comment: I am looking at AD to test the feature of my app.

Comment: I don't understand either. What does AD have to do with collecting the "last backup date for databases"? The last backup date is never stored in AD.

Comment: Please check this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-ms-sql-lastbackupdate

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for editing.